# Who was expelled from Avraham's house and married an Egyptian?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, vayera

[*Vayera* 21:9–21](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T0121) speaks repeatedly of *Hagar*'s son without once naming him. In no particular order, *Rashi*  ([:17](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8216/showrashi/true#v17)), pseudo-*Yonasan* (:11), the *Rav miBartinura* ([:14](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40021&pgnum=13)), *Ramban* ([:9](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%90#.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.95.D7.A7_.D7.98_.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.A7.29.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.95.D7.A7.29)), *Chizkuni* (:14), *Toldos Yitzchak* (*R' Yitzchak Karo*), and *Ralbag* (*beur hamilos* :17) mention in passing, as if it's obvious, that this was *Yishmael*, and, indeed, we know of no other son of *Hagar*'s. I wonder, though,

- whether any Jewish commentaries suggest that this was not *Yishmael*, and
- whether there's indication from the text of the *Chumash* (besides our not knowing of any other son of *Hagar*'s) that this was *Yishmael*.

Comment: The [Ramban](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%90#.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.95.D7.A7_.D7.98_.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.A7.29.28.D7.9B.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A4.D7.A1.D7.95.D7.A7.29) explains why the posuk does not mention Yishmael by name

Comment: As does [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41457&pgnum=18) sefer

Comment: As I mentioned in [my comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22027/who-was-expelled-from-avrahams-house-and-married-an-egyptian#comment50118_22036) to Raffy's answer, the passage makes it pretty clear. If we cannot easily understand that this must be Yishma'el, then how do we understand that "the lad" and "Hagar's son" are the same person? How do you know the passage isn't talking about a different person in each instance? Furthermore, how can we be certain that this is the same Hagar who married Avraham at the behest of Sarah? Maybe that's why Sarah was displeased?

Comment: @SethJ, in context within the _parasha_ (not _Vayera_ but the paragraph), obviously (or, at least, very likely) the lad and the boy and the son are the same. How do we know his name, though?

Comment: If you are going so far as to say that Hagar and Avraham had a second son not mentioned by the Torah, and that the Parashah is therefore ambiguous, you will have to address my second question to you, viz. which Hagar is the Parashah discussing?

Comment: @SethJ, but we find numerous examples of children not mentioned in the _Tora_ but mentioned in _midrashim_ (and even some compelled by the text). There are no examples I know of (not that that means there are no examples) of two wives of one man bearing the same name.

Comment: While it's not an example in Mikra, I refer you to [Bab. Gittin 24b (end of the Mishnah cont. from 24a)](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=gitin&daf=24b). Clearly this was a common enough occurrence to be a concern mentioned in the laws of divorce.

Answer (score 4):

Hagar only had one son from Avraham at the time. This is evident from [Rashi to 22:2](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=1&perek=22&mefaresh=rashi): "Take your only son." "Both are the only one to their mothers."

Comment: +1, very nice! Of course, that doesn't preclude the existence of _midrashim_ or commentaries that differ with it.

Answer (score 0):

Posuk 9 says '...whom she had born to Avrohom'. Avrohom only had one child from Hagar.

Comment: Didn't the question say "besides our not knowing of any other son of Hagar's"? (That's actually a stronger statement than yours. You say that Hagar only had one child through Avraham; the question excludes any child of Hagar at all. But that's really besides the point.)

Comment: @DoubleAA, but, but, but the passage speaks of "the lad" as "Avraham's son", multiple times. Pasuk 9 is only one example. See Pesukim 11 and 13 as well.  WADR to msh210, the question is flawed.  The fact that so many commentators (7 mentioned in the question) seem  to assume that it's obvious should further the point.  Bullet point 1 asks for other commentaries, which this does not answer.  But bullet point 2 asks if there is any indication from the text.  Yes!  The mention of him as Avraham's son (not just Hagar's)!

Comment: @SethJ, I guess I should have said in the question "besides our not knowing of any other son of _Avraham_ and _Hagar_'s" (which is really what I'd meant) rather than "besides our not knowing of any other son of _Hagar_'s". That is some indication, certainly, but I was looking for something further.

Comment: @SethJ Your points are strong, but that doesn't make this a good answer; it makes the question a weak (and possibly unanswerable) question.